# Trying to return a percentage of two rows from a variable table

Tags: sql-server

I have created a variable table which returns counts of total purchase orders and purchase orders completed. What I want to do next is get the On time delivery percentage of those two fields.
Here is what I have so far that works but I am at a loss of how to get the percentage of the two.

```
DECLARE @percentage TABLE (
            col1 VARCHAR (100)
            
);
INSERT INTO @percentage
SELECT       Count (DISTINCT dbo.PorMasterDetail.PurchaseOrder )
FROM            dbo.PorMasterDetail INNER JOIN
                dbo.PorMasterHdr ON dbo.PorMasterDetail.PurchaseOrder = dbo.PorMasterHdr.PurchaseOrder
WHERE           (dbo.PorMasterDetail.PurchaseOrder LIKE '0000000007%') AND (dbo.PorMasterDetail.MLatestDueDate BETWEEN GETDATE()-7 AND GETDATE()) AND (dbo.PorMasterHdr.OrderStatus <> '*')
UNION
SELECT Count (DISTINCT dbo.PorMasterDetail.PurchaseOrder)
FROM            dbo.PorMasterDetail INNER JOIN
                         dbo.PorMasterHdr ON dbo.PorMasterDetail.PurchaseOrder = dbo.PorMasterHdr.PurchaseOrder
WHERE        (dbo.PorMasterDetail.PurchaseOrder LIKE '0000000007%') AND (dbo.PorMasterDetail.MLatestDueDate BETWEEN GETDATE() - 7 AND GETDATE()) AND (dbo.PorMasterHdr.OrderStatus <> '*') AND LineType IN ('1', '7') AND MCompleteFlag = 'Y'
```

Currently when I Select * From @percentage I get the results,
Col1
182
244
I need to now get the percentage of those two numbers which will change daily.

Comment: you could do the straightforward approach, assign each count to a variable (Select @val2 = count(distinct.....)) then perform math on the variables. for final result just do (Select @finalresult) to generate an outgoing resultset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you are asking but hopefully this will give you an idea of how you might approach a solution

```
WITH X AS
(
SELECT Col1 = 182 UNION
SELECT Col1 = 244
)
SELECT
 Col1
,PctValue = Col1 * 100.00 / (SELECT SUM(Col1) FROM X)
FROM X
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all of you for the suggestions.
Ulysses got me the closest and here is what I ended up with that worked.

WITH TotalPosDueLast7 as
(
SELECT       'Total POs Due Within Last 7 Days' as Title,  Count (DISTINCT dbo.PorMasterDetail.PurchaseOrder )  AS Totals
FROM            dbo.PorMasterDetail INNER JOIN
dbo.PorMasterHdr ON dbo.PorMasterDetail.PurchaseOrder = dbo.PorMasterHdr.PurchaseOrder
WHERE        (dbo.PorMasterDetail.PurchaseOrder LIKE '0000000007%') AND (dbo.PorMasterDetail.MLatestDueDate BETWEEN GETDATE()-30 AND GETDATE()) AND (dbo.PorMasterHdr.OrderStatus <> '*')
),
TotalPosCompleted as
(
SELECT      'Total POs Completed' as Title, Count (DISTINCT dbo.PorMasterDetail.PurchaseOrder) as Totals
FROM            dbo.PorMasterDetail INNER JOIN
dbo.PorMasterHdr ON dbo.PorMasterDetail.PurchaseOrder = dbo.PorMasterHdr.PurchaseOrder
WHERE        (dbo.PorMasterDetail.PurchaseOrder LIKE '0000000007%') AND (dbo.PorMasterDetail.MLatestDueDate BETWEEN GETDATE() - 30 AND GETDATE()) AND (dbo.PorMasterHdr.OrderStatus <> '*') AND LineType IN ('1', '7') AND MCompleteFlag = 'Y'
)
,TotalPosDue (Tile, Totals) as
(
SELECT      'Total PO Due', Count (dbo.PorMasterDetail.Line)

```
FROM            dbo.PorMasterDetail INNER JOIN
                         dbo.PorMasterHdr ON dbo.PorMasterDetail.PurchaseOrder = dbo.PorMasterHdr.PurchaseOrder
WHERE        (dbo.PorMasterDetail.PurchaseOrder LIKE '0000000007%') AND (dbo.PorMasterDetail.MLatestDueDate BETWEEN GETDATE() - 30 AND GETDATE()) AND (dbo.PorMasterHdr.OrderStatus <> '*') AND 
                         (dbo.PorMasterDetail.LineType IN ('1', '7')) AND MCompleteFlag IN ('Y', ' ')
```

)
, LinesReceived (Tile, Totals) as
(
SELECT     'Lines Received', Count (dbo.PorMasterDetail.Line)
FROM            dbo.PorMasterDetail INNER JOIN
dbo.PorMasterHdr ON dbo.PorMasterDetail.PurchaseOrder = dbo.PorMasterHdr.PurchaseOrder
WHERE        (dbo.PorMasterDetail.PurchaseOrder LIKE '0000000007%') AND (dbo.PorMasterDetail.MLatestDueDate BETWEEN GETDATE()- 30AND GETDATE()) AND (dbo.PorMasterHdr.OrderStatus <> '*') AND
(dbo.PorMasterDetail.LineType IN ('1', '7')) AND MCompleteFlag = 'Y'
AND NOT MLastReceiptDat IS NULL
)
, LinesOpen (Tile, Totals) as
(
SELECT       'Lines Open', Count (dbo.PorMasterDetail.Line)
FROM            dbo.PorMasterDetail INNER JOIN
dbo.PorMasterHdr ON dbo.PorMasterDetail.PurchaseOrder = dbo.PorMasterHdr.PurchaseOrder
WHERE        (dbo.PorMasterDetail.PurchaseOrder LIKE '0000000007%') AND (dbo.PorMasterDetail.MLatestDueDate BETWEEN GETDATE()-30 AND GETDATE()) AND (dbo.PorMasterHdr.OrderStatus <> '*')
AND LineType IN ('1', '7') AND MLastReceiptDat IS NULL
)
select * from TotalPosDueLast7
UNION
select * from TotalPosCompleted
UNION
select * from TotalPosDue
UNION
select * from LinesReceived
UNION
select * from LinesOpen
UNION
select 'Avg' as Title, ROUND((100.0 * tpc.Totals) / (tpd.Totals) , 2) as Totals
from TotalPosCompleted as tpc
cross join TotalPosDueLast7 as tpd